# iOS Using delegate through 2 class

Tags: ios, delegates

i have 3 class : ListItem, ListPageView, ListViewController

there is code in ListViewController when loaded item :

```
ListPageView *pageView = [[ListPageView alloc] init];
pageView.delegate = self;
for(NSDictionary *_itemDetails in res)
{
    // khởi tạo item của list
    ListItem *item = [[ListItem alloc] initWithImage:[MEDIA_SERVER stringByAppendingString:[_itemDetails objectForKey:@"image"]]];
    item.data = _itemDetails; // copy
    item.center = CGPointMake(colIndex * 165 + 230 + colIndex * 30, rowIndex * 125 + 120 + rowIndex * 10);
    // gán tổng số page hiện có trên server
    _totalPage = [[_itemDetails objectForKey:@"pages"] intValue];
    // delegate vào self để gọi sự kiện click
    item.delegate = pageView;
    item.tag = ITEM_TAG + i;
    i++;
    // set Index
    colIndex++;
    if(colIndex == 4)
    {
        rowIndex++;
        colIndex = 0;
    }

    [pageView addSubview:item];
}
[self.view addSubview:pageView];
```

problem is if i directly add ListItem into self.view, ListViewController can delegate touch event of ListItem. but if i add ListItem into ListPageView then add ListPageView into self.view ListViewController cant delegate touch event from ListItem.

List item delegate :

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ListItemBeginTouched:)])
{
    [_delegate ListItemBeginTouched:self];
}
```

ListPageView delegate :

```
-(void)ListItemBeginTouched:(ListItem *)listItem
{
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ItemBeginTouched:withPageView:)])
{
    [_delegate ItemBeginTouched:listItem withPageView:self];
}
}
```

Comment: you might want to try to implement hitTest and/or pointInside

More infos there : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to set frame to pageView. thanks for answers :)